# Механизм работы СУБД - зачем нужен универсальный драйвер ODBC, если есть универсальный язык SQL?

Tags: sql, база-данных, драйвер, odbc

Собственно вопрос, каков механизм выполнения запросов к СУБД (например, пусть это будет MySQL) и какова роль в этом механизме таких компонентов, как язык SQL и ODBC?
Непонятно вот что, если есть универсальный язык выполнения запросов, который нивелирует различия между СУБД, зачем нужен ещё и универсальный драйвер?

Comment: sql (язык) - не универсален. Есть диалекты. odbc это один из стандартов (библиотек), позволяющий как сделать запрос, так и узнать список таблиц полей процедур не используя запросы. Кроме odbc есть ещё jdbc, oledb и другие.

Comment: @nick_n_a, наличие диалектов не отменяет его универсальности, в противном случае в нём бы не было необходимости. Большинство запросов, написанных в соответствии со стандартом, будут одинаково интерпретированы на большинстве реляционных СУБД. А если вы под _диалектами_ понимаете нечто вроде T-SQL или PL/SQL, ну так это скорее процедурные расширения универсального SQL, о которых, замечу, в вопросе речи не шло.

Comment: Вам правильно ответили. sql = язык. odbc = библиотека (интерфейс для драйверов) к СУБД. odbc может выполнять sql, а sql выполнять odbc нет (sql не связан с odbc). Под универсальностью я имел ввиду то что `sql(mysql):show tables` не будет равен `sql(mssql):select * from sys.tables`, а в odbc предусмотрена функция типа gettables которая всегда одинаково вернёт список таблиц для любой СУБД.

Answer (score 4):

SQL это язык запросов. ODBC это способ подключения к конкретному серверу конкретной БД. Все БД имеют разные протоколы для доступа к серверу БД. ODBC предоставляет унифицированный интерфейс и скрывает конкретную реализацию протокола доступа.

Answer (score 2):

Задача драйвера не только передать SQL-запрос серверу, такой протокол передачи можно было бы стандартизироать, если бы он был просто текстом. Но есть такая вещь как передаваемые в запрос параметры и самое главное - результат выполнения запроса. Задача драйвера упаковывать запрос, параметры и результаты в пакеты передаваемые по сети. И формат упаковки языком никак не оговаривается и каждая СУБД реализует его по своему. Тем более, что во многих СУБД существуют не только разные типы данных, но и сложные типы, например, как массивы PostgreSQL, которых в стандартах SQL вообще нет. И как передавать по сети эти типы данных опять же каждая БД решает самостоятельно.

Поэтому для работы с СУБД программы линкуются с библиотеками (драйверами) конкретных СУБД, которые умеют общаться с конкретной БД. Драйвер ODBC предназначен для того, что бы программа могла быть слинкована с единственной библиотекой и через нее получать доступ к разным БД, понятно, что при этом программа не сможет получить доступ к не стандартным типам данных и надо будет ограничиваться в работе стандартизированными, боле менее одинаковыми в разных СУБД возможностям языка SQL.